# How to relocate Dropbox folder to sdc1 drive in Linux Mint 21?

Tags: linux-mint, sync, dropbox

I've installed Dropbox (Flatpack) and everything is working fine as long as I just let Dropbox use it's default folder or keeps the folder on the system drive. The problem is that I would like to have the Dropbox folder on another drive, which is found under /media. When I enter Dropbox Preferences -> Synchronization -> Directory, Dropbox can't see /media. I've tried to enter the path but it doesn't work.

The disk I want to reach is mounted and is working/accessible for other programs.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Apps installed through Flatpak are running in isolated containers which are only allowed to see the specific parts of the system that they request upfront. (Similar to the permission system in Android or iOS apps.)

Install the [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) app (which is also available through Flatpak) and use it to grant Dropbox access to `/media` or other parts of the filesystem.